# Log a web page's dynamically-created, DOM elements with a userscript

Tags: javascript, dom, userscripts

I want to extract all the dynamic javascript functions from a web page, with a userscript.

Someone suggested using a hook for DOM objects. They also provided this example:

```
var f = document.createElement;document.createElement = function(tagName){ 
console.log(tagName); 
f.apply(document, arguments); }
```

I think this functions logs all the `document.createElement()` calls, 
but where do I add this function in my userscript?
I tried creating a userscript which contains only this function, but it did not work.

The userscript gets executed after the page is loaded. How can this function be changed so that it tracks the dynamic functions before hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To track all dynamically loaded arguments "before hand", use [`// @run-at document-start`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at).

Also, you must inject the code into the target page, because the page's javascript is what you want to track.

Here is a complete script that logs all `createElement()` calls.  It works with both Greasemonkey (Firefox) and Chrome userscripts:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Track dynamically added elements
// @namespace   Your PC
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Intercept and log document.createElement().
function LogNewTagCreations () {
    var oldDocumentCreateElement    = document.createElement;

    document.createElement          = function (tagName) {
        var elem = oldDocumentCreateElement.apply (document, arguments);
        console.log ("Dynamically created a(n)", tagName, " tag.  Link: ", elem);
        return elem;
    }
}

/*--- The userscript or GM script will start running before the DOM is available.
    Therefore, we wait...
*/
var waitForDomInterval = setInterval (
    function () {
        var domPresentNode;
        if (typeof document.head == "undefined")
            domPresentNode = document.querySelector ("head, body");
        else
            domPresentNode = document.head;
        if (domPresentNode) {
            clearInterval (waitForDomInterval);
            addJS_Node (null, null, LogNewTagCreations);
        }
    },
    1
);

//--- Handy injection function.
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much can you explain this more clearly i wrote this userscript and installed it in firefox but there is nothing printed on web console can you help me with this

Comment: Did you change `http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*` to some meaningful value for the web site you are interested in?  What version of Greasemonkey are you using.  The Script won't log anything if the page does not actually create nodes dynamically.  Link to the target page.

Comment: i want this for every site i view can i remove @include

Comment: Thank you it is working. i was just trying to do this from past 4 days you made my work easy thank you so much

Comment: i am trying to retrieve the attribute values from the above function as follows can i do this `if(tagName=="script")
        {
            console.log("------------",elem.attributes.src.Value);
        }`

Comment: Please ask a new question for that.  The short answer is, "No, not right away. The `src` is not set until after `createElement()` completes (if ever). You can use a timer delay or track script nodes specially."  Again, please ask a new question for that.

Comment: You would use the *concepts* from this script in add-on builder, and maybe some snippets of code.  But, checking for the DOM and adding scripts are handled differently for add-ons than userscripts, and you want to use privileged API's that are only available to add-ons. ... At this point, you need either a tutorial or training, or to pay someone to write this for you.  It's too much to put in one or two SO questions or to handle via comments or chat.  Good luck.

Comment: We help for free and on our own time.  No one has to help.  If I saw a personal use for this kind of add-on, or had a shortage of problems to work on, I might take up this project -- but I don't, and it's too involved for just a few minutes effort. ... The system banned you from asking questions for a reason.  Please read [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/148310) and follow the advice.

Comment: Thank you so much and once again sorry for wasting your invaluable time

Comment: You're welcome and I never accused you of wasting my time.  I apologize for not realizing sooner that Greasemonkey was not a good tool for your task. ... Follow the advice on that page.