# Log a web page's dynamically-created tag attributes with a userscript

Tags: javascript, dom, userscripts

I am able to track all the dynamically created tags, using Brock Adams' answer to ["Log a web page's dynamically-created, DOM elements with a userscript"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10083010/331508).

Now I want to get the attributes of the tags. I tried it by adding an if condition in `LogNewTagCreations ()` but it didn't work.
In this example I am checking attributes for script tags:

```
if(tagName=="script")
    {
        console.log("------------",elem.attributes.src.Value);
    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `<script>`s `src` is set outside the `createElement()` call, adapting [the previous script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083010/log-a-web-pages-dynamically-created-dom-elements-with-a-userscript) requires a little more work than that.  You must check for the `src` attribute essentially asynchronously.

One way to do that is with another polling interval.  Rolling that into [the previous script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083010/log-a-web-pages-dynamically-created-dom-elements-with-a-userscript) (along with some housekeeping), the script code becomes:

```
//--- Intercept and log document.createElement().
function LogNewTagCreations () {
    var oldDocumentCreateElement    = document.createElement;

    document.createElement          = function (tagName) {
        var elem = oldDocumentCreateElement.apply (document, arguments);
        console.log ("Dynamically created a(n)", tagName, " tag.  Link: ", elem);

        if (tagName == "script") {
            GetScriptAttributes (elem);
        }

        return elem;
    }
}

function GetScriptAttributes (elem, tagNum, timerIntVar) {
    /*--- Because a <script>s src or text won't be set for some while, we need
        to poll for when they are added.
    */
    GetScriptAttributes.tagNum  = GetScriptAttributes.tagNum || 0;
    if ( ! tagNum) {
        GetScriptAttributes.tagNum++;
        tagNum = GetScriptAttributes.tagNum;
    }

    if (elem.src) {
        doneWaiting ();
        console.log (
            "Script tag", tagNum,
            " has a src attribute of:", elem.src
        );
    }
    else if (elem.textContent) {
        doneWaiting ();
        console.log (
            "Script tag", tagNum,
            " has a JS code of:", elem.textContent
        );
    }
    else {
        if ( ! timerIntVar) {
            var timerIntVar = setInterval (
                function () {
                    GetScriptAttributes (elem, tagNum, timerIntVar);
                },
                50
            );
        }
    }

    function doneWaiting () {
        if (timerIntVar) {
            clearInterval (timerIntVar);
        }
    }
}

/*--- The userscript or GM script will start running before the DOM is available.
    Therefore, we wait...
*/
var waitForDomInterval = setInterval (
    function () {
        var domPresentNode;
        if (typeof document.head == "undefined")
            domPresentNode = document.querySelector ("head, body");
        else
            domPresentNode = document.head;
        if (domPresentNode) {
            clearInterval (waitForDomInterval);
            addJS_Node (GetScriptAttributes.toString() );
            addJS_Node (null, null, LogNewTagCreations);
        }
    },
    1
);

//--- Handy injection function.
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the code and i am having problem in understanding textContent for script tag

Comment: There are 2 ways a dynamically added script gets its code.  `src` is one, and `textContent` is the other.  Given `<script>alert("Hello");</script>`, the `textContent` would be `alert("Hello");`.

Comment: As for the code, it's the same as the code in your other question but with `GetScriptAttributes()` added.  That function is modified from one I use occasionally and explaining it fully may be beyond scope here.  Essentially, it sets up a timer for every added script element.  When each `<script>` finally gets either a `src` or code text (which could be long after the `<script>` was created), `GetScriptAttributes()` processes the result for that script and stops that script's timer.  You should see it reported in the console (I tested it, and it works).

Comment: I am able to track all the dynamically created tags, using Brock Adams' answer to "Log a web page's dynamically-created tag attributes with a userscrip".

Now I am getting the src attributes of script tag. what i want to do this is to place all the src attributes in an array and display the array in alert box i did like in the following way

Comment: That's a new question [which you have already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10103985/331508).  Mark this question as complete and we may answer the next one.  But beware that Stack Overflow is neither a code-writing nor a tutorial service.

Comment: i have a basic doubt here we are doing all this before the document is loaded now if i add some other functions in this userscript and i want to run the function after this activity than how do i know that the above function has finished parsing the page.

Comment: Some modern AJAX pages will NEVER finish.  If you are running on one of those, you need to change your approach.  For everything else, fire on the `load` event.  However, **this** question is answered.

Comment: i asked this because i am trying to print all the tags identified at a time in an array. sorry to bother you because i don't what to make another question for this that is why i thought of asking here. I am not understanding where to print the array.

Comment: where can i print the complete array

Comment: That will be answered in your other question, **IF** someone decides to answer it.  Please review [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) -- especially the 4 "Related" links on the right.

Comment: I have to use the functionality of an external javascript file "esprima.js" i tried to add this file to webpage like this `addJS_Node (null,"esprima.js");` but this is not working can you help me please

Comment: That call would be correct only if "esprima.js" is in the same folder as the main web page.  Use the correct path or full URL otherwise.  Open a new question for anything more.