# Using DOM events to print the count of document.createElement calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, userscripts

As per this post [Log a web page's dynamically-created tag attributes with a userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085343/log-a-web-pages-dynamically-created-tag-attributes-with-a-userscript)

i retrieved the attributes and also included the array as suggested like

`addJS_Node ("var arr=[];");`

i successfully pushed the src attributes to arr array because i didn't get any error.

Now i am confused where to display the array.

My code is as follows

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Tags Monitoring
// @namespace   PC
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==
//--- Intercept and log document.createElement().tagattributes
addJS_Node ("var arr=[];"); 
function LogNewTagCreations ()
{   
   var oldDocumentCreateElement = document.createElement;
  document.createElement       = function (tagName) 
  {
      var elem = oldDocumentCreateElement.apply (document, arguments);  
      if(tagName=='script')      
         GetScriptAttributes (elem); 
     return elem;
  }   
}
function GetScriptAttributes (elem, tagNum, timerIntVar) 
{
   /*--- Because the tags won't be set for some while, we need
    to poll for when they are added.
   */       
   GetScriptAttributes.tagNum  = GetScriptAttributes.tagNum || 0;
   if ( ! tagNum) 
   {
       GetScriptAttributes.tagNum++;
       tagNum = GetScriptAttributes.tagNum;
   }   
   /*-- Getting the required attributes */
   if (elem.src) 
   {
      doneWaiting ();
      arr.push(elem.src);
        console.log (
        tagNum," has a src attribute of:", elem.src,"=========",arr.length
        );
   }    
   else 
   {
    if ( ! timerIntVar) 
    {
        var timerIntVar = setInterval 
        (
            function () 
            {
                GetScriptAttributes (elem, tagNum, timerIntVar);

            },
            50
        );            
    }        
}    
function doneWaiting () 
{
    if (timerIntVar) 
    {
        clearInterval (timerIntVar);
    }       
}    
}
 /*--- The userscript or GM script will start running before the DOM is available.
   Therefore, we wait...
  */
  var waitForDomInterval = setInterval (
  function () {
    var domPresentNode;
    if (typeof document.head == "undefined")
        domPresentNode = document.querySelector ("head, body");
    else
        domPresentNode = document.head;       
    if (domPresentNode) {
        clearInterval (waitForDomInterval);            
        addJS_Node (GetScriptAttributes.toString() );                    
        addJS_Node (null, null, LogNewTagCreations);
    }
},
1  
);

 addJS_Node("document.onreadystatechange = function (){if (document.readyState ==       'complete'){console.log(arr.length);}}");

//--- Handy injection function.
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
var D                                   = document;
var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';
var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
targ.appendChild (scriptNode);    
}
```

I want to print the number of tags created dynamically that is why i added array. I first tried with script tags only and how can i know the array is completed and so that i can print the array length

Comment: i tried `addJS_Node("document.onreadystatechange = function (){if (document.readyState == 'complete'){console.log(arr.length);}}");` i am getting 0 at starting and at the end it is again printing 3 whereas the actual length is 5 Please Help me i am trying this for past 1 week but i am not able to figure when to print the array

Comment: sure. post your full code explain what you want to do.

Comment: I want to print the array length but i am not sure where to include the console.log() method. i added a DOM event in the above code but i am getting more tags than the array length. i.e, i am getting the tags printed even after the array length is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is not with your code.
You simply dont know javascript at all.

I strongly recommend you start with simple codes and tutorials.
Try to code your first script.
If you have any doubt about your **code**, feel free to come and ask about it.

The code that Brock Adams gave you is working perfectly.
I just copy-pasted it into Greasemonkey.
Here is the output:

[image]

And please go back to [Log a web page's dynamically-created tag attributes with a userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085343/log-a-web-pages-dynamically-created-tag-attributes-with-a-userscript) and mark his answer as the right one.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code even it is working perfectly for me that is why i included it.I want to print the number of tags created dynamically that is why i added array. I first tried with script tags only and how can i know the array is completed and so that i can print the array length

Comment: See what you did? This text, that you just wrote in the comments section, explains what you really want! This should be your question, not your comment! People really need to learn how to ask...

Comment: By the way, you could ask Brock Adams to change `GetScriptAttributes.tagNum` to count all tags.

Comment: He only suggested to use Events so i added `document.onreadystatechange` but it is not yielding complete result so i posted the question