# Get the innerHTML of  [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLDivElement]] object

Tags: javascript, userscripts

In my userscript i created a hook of document.createElement the code i used is the solution provided by Brock adams in the below post

[Log a web page's dynamically-created, DOM elements with a userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083010/log-a-web-pages-dynamically-created-dom-elements-with-a-userscript)

Now when i run this userscript in firefox and print the `elem` in `LogNewTagCreations ()` method like this `console.log(elem)` i am getting the output as `[object XrayWrapper [object HTMLDivElement]]` in this format. Now how can i get the `innerHTML` property of the tag or entire tag like this `<div>Sometext</div>` so that i can get `innerHTML` from this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that the `XrayWrapper` used by Greasemonkey to wrap around *DOM elements* is quite an imperfect wrapper, since it doesn't really support the `innerHTML` getter/setter.

I wrote you a simplistic recursive `innerHTML` implementation, call it like this: `html(element)`. It ignores everything but elements, attributes and text nodes, but it should serve its purpose as long as the `XrayWrapper` supports the other *DOM attributes* I use in the function.

```
var html = (function() {
  var ELEMENT = this.Node?Node.ELEMENT_NODE:1,
         TEXT = this.Node?Node.TEXT_NODE:   3;
  return function html(el, outer) {
    var i = 0, j = el.childNodes, k = outer?"<" + (m = el.nodeName.toLowerCase()) + attr(el) + ">":"",
        l = j.length, m, n;
    while(i !== l) switch((n = j[i++]).nodeType) {
      case ELEMENT: k += html(n, true); break;
      case TEXT:    k += n.nodeValue;
    } return k + (outer?"</" + m + ">":"");
  }; function attr(el) {
    var i = 0, j = el.attributes, k = new Array(l = j.length), l, m;
    while(i !== l) k[i] = (m = j[i++].nodeName) + "=\"" + el.getAttribute(m) + "\"";
    return (l?" ":"") + k.join(" ");
  }
})();
```

Comment: hi witiko, I faced the same thing like [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLLIElement]] when I tried to get an li. So I want to convert those li element to HTML object where I want to check $("#result li").each(function(index) { }. but when I call ur function html() like, I am getting html is not a function. How can I use ur function to convert into HTML object?

Comment: @kitokid you may want to make your own question

Comment: @SomeKittens yes. I want to. but I am afraid it will be closed because of remarked as duplicate.